# How to generate a list of values related to calculating angles of a polygon? (One solution already created)

Tags: geometry

[image]

I want to generate this exact list

I have this code and it works perfectly however I want to do it in a different way without using these functions, can someone please help me do this?

```
x = 180 (p - 2 q)/p


DeleteCases[
 Flatten[
  Table[
   If[
    IntegerQ[x],
    If[x > 0,
     If[GCD[p, q] == 1,
      {p, q, x}
      ]
     ]
    ],
   {p, 3, 40, 1},
   {q, 1, p/2}],
  1
  ],
 Null
 ]
```

What is another solution to this problem?